# Fire and Forget with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm looking for info on best practices for a fire and forget asp.net mvc action ... essentially I want a mobile client to make a call; the server start an async task; and then return to the mobile client as fast as possible.

But I want to make sure that, assuming no exceptions, the async task will complete successfully. There's obviously a few different options:

- Make a new Thread
- Queue a work item on the ThreadPool
- Begin an async delegate call
- Start a Task

I assume the Task would be the best option here, but wanted to get thoughts from SO.

*Edit:* to clarify based on a few of the answers already: The client doesn't need a response. I want the HTTP request to complete as fast as possible as soon as the server begins the async task. I know about async patterns on the client, however I want to limit the amount of time the mobile device needs to maintain a connection open. Also, want to avoid having a separate process which polls or is pushed a message (via queue, bus, etc.) because that's overkill. I just want to log something in a database, the client doesn't need to remain connected until that IO is finished.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but here's my take on such things, for what it's worth, since I disagree with the accepted answer.

You don't need an `AsyncController` because you are not interested in waiting for your async operations to complete.  So the answer to your question with respect to the MVC side of things is: it doesn't matter.  You can do your work any which way and have just a regular old action that kicks off the process and returns whatever result you want.

The second part of your question is really more relevant.  You want to make sure nothing is going to happen to your async tasks given that you've started them from your web process, assuming a task itself does not throw an exception.  The answer to this depends on your reliability requirements.

You mentioned that you don't want a separate process, and this limits your options.  Your tasks will be running in the same app domain with your web application.  If anything brings down the app domain or the process, your tasks will die, potentially in a strange state.  This isn't necessarily even from unhandled exceptions.  IIS can be set to automatically recycle an application from time to time or in certain conditions.  Or if you release new code or touch anything in the bin directory, your app domain will be torn down after all requests are finished, and a new one is started.  If these cases are a show-stopper for you, then you have no choice but to move your tasks out of process and communicate with some sort of messaging.

If you are not worried about IIS killing you, you still have to worry about yourself.  Unhandled exceptions from other background tasks will bring down the process if you don't last-chance handle them with the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event.  In the case of using the Task Parallel Library, Tasks with exceptions that you don't observe by `Wait`ing on them or viewing the `Result` or `Exception` properties will bring down the process if you don't last-chance observe them in the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event.

A further note is that any ThreadPool threads used for your background operations will not be able to serve requests for your web application during that time.  You could manage the max threads in the pool, or instead start a new Thread.  Or if you're using TPL with the default scheduler, schedule the task with the `LongRunning` hint to effectively gain a new thread.

Answer (score 12):

### Cleaner fire and forget with TPL and Mvc 4

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() 
{
  // Start all operations.
  var tasks = new[]
  {
    Task.Run(() =>TestOutput.DoWork("1")), 
    Task.Run(() =>TestOutput.DoWork("2")), 
    Task.Run(() =>TestOutput.DoWork("3"))
  };

  // Asynchronously wait for them all to complete.
// Uncomment below line to not forget the results
//  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

  // Return empty string for fire and forget.
  return View(string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: to be more clear, here Index is the controller method, which needs to be fired and forgotten :)     . TestOutput.DoWork(string var) is the long running task which will be running in the server side. It could be any server side method

Answer (score 1):

You are being contradictory

Your question title explicitly says "Fire and Forget" and then in your question you mention the opposite

> essentially I want a mobile client to make a call; the server start an async task; **and then return** to the mobile client as fast as possible.

So, you want an **async call** that will send a result back, or a **Fire and forget** call?

---

**If a normal async call**, just use the jQuery `.ajax()` method your the same in your favorite javascript library, and hook up your return in the `success` property function.

---

**If a fire and forget**, the best way is to ask the server to insert a row in a `TBL_JOBS` table in the database, then you can have a recurring script that picks this up and process the information.

Comment: my mistake as it seems I wasn't clear, I do not want a response returned to the client. I just want the client to make the http call, the server kicks off the job, and then without waiting for that job to finish, to conclude the http response. I would also prefer to avoid a separate job/process

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an `AsyncController`.  You should look at the AsyncController area from the sample code for Brad Wilson's Advanced MVC3 presentation, at http://bradwilson.typepad.com/presentations/advanced-mvc-3.zip

Comment: With an async controller, the client still waits for the eventual completion of the task before the http request is considered complete. I want the http call to complete and return to the client nearly immediateyl

Comment: @Joel Martinez, AFAIK, you do not have to have your async action wait for the action to complete if you do not need to send the result to the client.  I have not done a deep dive into the code, but I do not see why you must wait for the async action to complete.

Comment: as I understand it (and I could be wrong), the async action is more to streamline the way the server handles the requests. Frees up the pipeline during IO-bound activity to handle other requests from other clients. So I think it has to be paired with a completed action, and the client's http connection stays alive for the whole duration ... I would love to be proven wrong though :-)

Comment: @Joel Martinez, while it is not what I would call strictly kosher, you can call `AsyncManager.Finish()` from your called routine, and your ...Completed() method will be started immediately.