# How to to make sure that the API only processes one request at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

**Background:** I need to write a REST api wrapper for a 3rd party client dll. However, they're saying that the dlls are not thread safe and we should make sure that our REST api only process one request at a time.

**Question:** How should we do it? It's my first time dealing with this kind of scenario so I'm currently exploring how possible this is.

Comment: you can use Queue and execute request one by one

Comment: have a look at this similar question [Make .net web API queue requests operate 'single threaded'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31520322/2417602)

Answer (score -1):

You can allow a single request at API using the locking mechanisms. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class Test 
{
  private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult MethodName
  {
       lock (_lockObject)
        {
          //TODO: your code here.
        }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I have tested this stuff, and it's working. you may further elaborate on your issue in detail so that I may help you.